# Javascript gives me wrong image name from php listing

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

so, I'm beginner in javascript and I don't know why it gives me wrong image src. Actually it gives me just the src of first image from php listing.

Here's my code:

```
<php
  $files = glob("./images/*.*");
     for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
      {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $supported_file = array(
                'gif',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
         );

         $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {

            echo '<a target="_self">';
      echo '<img src="'.$image .'" onclick="list();" id="img" style="width:100px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Random image">';
            echo '</a>';
            } else {
                continue;
            }
          }

   ?>
<script>
function list(){
     var pic = document.getElementById("img").src;
     alert(pic);
} </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using html id attribute to get the image name, id means unique.But here all of your image ids are same, so you need to assign unique id for every elements. And change your code like this

```
 <?php
 $files = glob("./images/*.*");
 for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
 {
  $image = $files[$i];
  $supported_file = array(
                    'gif',
                    'jpg',
                    'jpeg',
                    'png'
  );

  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
  echo '<a target="_self">';
  echo '<img src="'.$image .'" onclick="list(this);" id="img" style="width:100px; margin- 
  right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="hover-shadow cursor" alt="Random image">';
  echo '</a>';
 } else {
   continue;
 }
}

?>
 <script>
    function list(img){
         var pic = img.src;
         alert(pic);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to even have `id` on the images. Giving each image a unique `id` makes it difficult to expand the code for the arbitrary number of images.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute must be unique for every element on the page. Here you have a bunch of images with the same `id` and the code selects the first one. Don't do that.

Instead, select images using `querySelectorAll`, for example:

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
```

Alternatively, if you only want to select some images, give them the `class="selectable"` attribute in your php code and then select them using:

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".selectable");
```

This gives you an array of all images on the page. Now you can iterate through it like this:

```
for (const pic of images) {
  alert(pic.src);
}
```

In any case, do not have two or more elements on the page with the same `id`, that will only create problems for you.